# C# Winforms // Delete data from the specific cell of DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I'm basically trying to make a bookkeeping program, which has three columns for the amount (numbers).

I want the amount of 'income', 'expense' and 'savings' go into different cells, even though they are categorized in the same column in the database (SQLite).

So I need to seperate them to the different columns when adding data to the DataGridView.

I ended up thinking of inserting the 'amount' data to every 3 columns and remove the unnecessary cells after. (I don't think this is the good way to solve the problem but still, it was my best.)

[This is how my DataGridView looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aKul9.jpg)

Below is how I inserted data to the DataGridView.

```
private void datagridviewUpdate()
        {
            conn = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=transaction.db;Version=3");
            conn.Open();

            SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand("SELECT type, date, category, subcategory, amount FROM list", conn);
            using (SQLiteDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    if (dr.GetValue(dr.GetOrdinal("type")).ToString() == "income")
                    {
                        dataGridView1.Rows.Add(new object[] {
                            dr.GetValue(dr.GetOrdinal("date")),
                            dr.GetValue(dr.GetOrdinal("type")),
                            dr.GetValue(dr.GetOrdinal("category")),
                            dr.GetValue(dr.GetOrdinal("subcategory")),
                            dr.GetValue(dr.GetOrdinal("amount")),
                            dr.GetValue(dr.GetOrdinal("amount"))
                    });
                    //so on...
                    }
                }
                dr.Close();
            }
            conn.Close();
        }
```

Below is what I tried:

```
private void eliminateAmount()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.RowCount; i++)
            {
                if(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value.ToString() == "income")
                {
                    dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value = null;
                }
                // so on...
            }
        }
```

It gives me the following error message: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Any brilliant idea and help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: How will you remember which they are for next time? Does Category define what column it goes im, for example?

Comment: If `Value` is null, you cannot call `.ToString()` on it. `ToString` is a method all objects have. But `null` is not an object. It is the absence of an object. Instead, use `dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value?.ToString()`. See [Null-conditional operators](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/member-access-operators#null-conditional-operators--and-). See also [Bind data to the DataGridView control](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/controls/how-to-bind-data-to-the-windows-forms-datagridview-control?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8).

Comment: with using statements - no need to call dr.close().  Why cant you just delete record from database?  Maybe adding more tables for , expense, savings and income.